# MongoDB - distinct with query doesn't use indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using Mongo 3.2.

Let's say I have a collection with this schema:

```
{ _id: 1, type: a, source: x },
{ _id: 2, type: a, source: y },
{ _id: 3, type: b, source: x },
{ _id: 4, type: b, source: y }
```

Of course that my db is much larger and with many more types and sources.

I have created 4 indexes combinations of type and source (even though 1 should be enough):

```
{type: 1}
{source: 1},
{type: 1, source: 1},
{source: 1, type: 1}
```

Now, I am running this distinct query:

```
db.test.distinct("source", {type: "a"})
```

The problem is that this query takes much more time that it should take.
If I run it with runCommand:

```
db.runCommand({distinct: 'test', key: "source", query: {type: "a"}})
```

this is the result i get:

```
{
    "waitedMS": 0,
    "values": [
        "x",
        "y"
    ],
    "stats": {
        "n": 19400840,
        "nscanned": 19400840,
        "nscannedObjects": 19400840,
        "timems": 14821,
        "planSummary": "IXSCAN { type: 1 }"
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

For some reason, mongo use only the `type: 1` index for the query stage.
It should use the index also for the distinct stage.
Why is that? Using the `{type: 1, source: 1}` index would be much better, no? right now it is scanning all the `type: a` documents while it has an index for it.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have a better option for this kind of distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex mentioned, apparently MongoDB doesn't support this right now.
There is an open issue for it:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19507

Comment: from the issue,looks like it should have been implemented in 3.4?

Comment: @Alvin Wong You are right, thankfully this feature has been implemented in Mongo 3.4.

Answer (score -2):

Just drop first 2 indexes. You don't need them. Mongo can use `{type: 1, source: 1}` in any query that may need `{type: 1}` index.

Comment: It doesn't change the results. Yea it will use the {type: 1, source: 1} index, but only for the query stage, not for the distinct stage, so the time and the resutls are the same

Comment: It does not use indexes for distinct stage, unless index start from the key. In your case `{source: 1}` can be used for `DISTINCT_SCAN` if query is empty.

Comment: I know, but this is not what I want. I want to distinct with a query, so it should use `DISTINCT_SCAN` on `{type: 1, source: 1}` index

Comment: Not doable atm. You can vote for the ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19507, but I don't think it's going to be resolved any soon.