# mongodb: How to use an index for distinct command and query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, distinct

I have some problems with very slow distinct commands that use a query. 
**From what I have observed the distinct command only makes use of an index if you do not specify a query**:

I have created a test database on my MongoDB 3.0.10 server with 1Mio objects. Each object looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e7fb5303858265f53c0ea1"),
    "field1" : "field1_6",
    "field2" : "field2_10",
    "field3" : "field3_29",
    "field4" : "field4_64"
}
```

The numbers at the end of the field values are random 0-99.

On the collections two simple indexes and one compound-index has been created:

```
{ "field1" : 1 } # simple index on "field1"
{ "field2" : 1 } # simple index on "field2"
{                # compound index on all fields
    "field2" : 1,
    "field1" : 1,
    "field3" : 1,
    "field4" : 1
}
```

Now I execute distinct queries on that database:

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: 'dbtest',key:'field1'})
```

The result contains 100 values, nscanned=100 and it has used index on "field1".

Now the same distinct query is limited by a query:

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: 'dbtest',key:'field1',query:{field2:"field2_10"}})
```

It contains again 100 values, however nscanned=9991 and the used index is the third one on all fields.

Now the third index that was used in the last query is dropped. Again the last query is executed:

```
db.runCommand({ distinct: 'dbtest',key:'field1',query:{field2:"field2_10"}})
```

It contains again 100 values, nscanned=9991 and the used index is the "field2" one.

Conclusion: If I execute a distinct command without query the result is taken directly from an index. However when I combine a distinct command with a query only the query uses an index, the distinct command itself does not use an index in such a case.

My problem is that I need to perform a distinct command with query on a very large database. The result set is very large but only contains ~100 distinct values. Therefore the complete distinct command takes ages (> 5 minutes) as it has to cycle through all values.

**What needs to be done to perform my distinct command presented above that can be answered by the database directly from an index?**

Comment: Currently not supported in mongo, duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006208/mongodb-distinct-with-query-doesnt-use-indexes

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. It is really great to have a "database" with data in it, well indexed and the "database" ignores the index. May be one should rethink about calling Mongo a database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is automatically used for distinct queries if your Mongo database version supports it.

The possibility to use an index in a distinct query requires Mongo version 3.4 or higher - it works for both storage engines MMAPv1/WiredTiger.

See also the bug ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19507

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I disagree - the question was "how can we use the index in distinct queries " and the answer as presented is "upgrade to Mongo 3.4". What answer do you expect? The question explicitly indicates that the necessary indices already exist.

Comment: The question was "how to use AN index ..." not "THE" index. I was personaly looking for a description of, well, how to define an index to work with distinct command (field orders, taking advantage of covered queries), since it's not documented. This may be the title of the question though, and not the answer

Comment: -1 is probably a bit rough on this though. The title of the question is way to wide. "how to use an index" doesn't mean anything. Should be either "how to defined index", or "how to make mongo use an index" i.e

Comment: Don't forget that the title is not the question itself. I gave an example what does not work and the resulting question was how to make it work with index. You really should take your time and read the complete question - and if it does not match your problem it is not a problem of the answer. Answers should be interpreted in the context of the question not in the context of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I read the question completely, and the question was edited 4 hours ago.
It was originaly "**What needs to be done to perform a distinct command with query that can be answered by the database directly from an index?**".

"Upgrading mongodb" does not answer the original question. I maintain.

Indeed, if you change the question, your answer is perfect.

Comment: Considering the presented distinct commands in the questions the answer is also correct -  before Mongo 3.4 it was simply not possible to to use any index if you have a `query`component.

Comment: Yeah that's true, and I was not saying you're answer is crap. I was just saying it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Max If an index exists it will be automatically used. Therefore there is nothing more necessary than the Mongo version. If you don't have to do anything what should I write? All the other details are already described in the question.

Comment: @Robert May be a link for further reading will be a good fit? Or source of information? Or anything else that helps to dig into your answer?

Comment: @Max I added the link to the bug ticket.